# How to check if any value in group is equal to a specific value in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset like the following:

```
ID|Date_Val|Data
1|2022-01-01|A
1|2022-01-01|I
1|2022-01-01|H
2|2022-01-01|G
2|2022-01-01|G
2|2022-01-01|I
```

I would like to run a query like the following:

```
SELECT ID, Date_Val, IF(/logic here/, 'A', 'B')
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Output dataset

```
ID|Date_Val|Data
1|2022-01-01|A
2|2022-01-01|B
```

How would I write `/logic here/` so that if any `Data` value in the grouping (ID, Date_Val) is `= 'A' then 'A' else 'B'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try:

```sql
SELECT ID, Date_Val,
       CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Data = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END AS Data
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Date_Val, 
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Data = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END as Data
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ID, Date_Val
```

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, another option would be:

```sql
SELECT ID, Date_Val, IF('A' IN UNNEST(ARRAY_AGG(Data)), 'A', 'B') Data
  FROM sample_table 
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is most compact version so far for you to consider

```
select id, date_val, 
  if(logical_or(data = 'A'), 'A', 'B') as data
from your_table
group by id, date_val
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]